# Search between dates but nothing shows when submit search

Tags: php, mysql

I know im doing it wrong because i edited this from just a name search can someone help me figure out what im doing wrong? Tried searching but nothing shows up.

```
    <form name="frmSearch" method="get" action="<?=$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];?>"
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
      <th>Search by date
      <input name="ftxtKeyword"  type="date" id="ftxtKeyword" value="<?=$_GET["ftxtKeyword"];?>"> Between
      <input name="btxtKeyword"  type="date" id="btxtKeyword" value="<?=$_GET["btxtKeyword"];?>">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Search">
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>

<?
if($_GET["ftxtKeyword"] != "")
    {
    $objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","1234") or die("Error Connect to Database");
    $objDB = mysql_select_db("mydatabase");
    $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM service WHERE Service_date BETWEEN ".$_GET["ftxtKeyword"]." AND ".$_GET["btxtKeyword"]."";
    $objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL) or die ("Error Query [".$strSQL."]");
    ?>
```

Comment: `echo $strSQL;` = debug

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[this happens](https://media.giphy.com/media/kg9t6wEQKV7u8/giphy.gif)**
 it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: You are missing `}` and wide open to sql injection.

Answer (score 2):

Your SQL statement, is not quoting the dates correctly.

Instead of

```
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM service WHERE Service_date BETWEEN ".$_GET["ftxtKeyword"]." AND ".$_GET["btxtKeyword"]."";
```

Change it to

```
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM service WHERE Service_date BETWEEN '".$_GET["ftxtKeyword"]."' AND '".$_GET["btxtKeyword"]."'";
```

**Few things to note:**

1. Do take @RiggsFolly's suggestion into account... do not use deprecated function, as when you eventually move to a server (or upgrade PHP to a higher version), you will run into a lot of headaches.
2. Avoid using PHP short tags for `echo`s. Instead of `<?=` use `<?php echo`. Why? Think what might happen when you move your code to an environment where `php.ini` settings has the short tags turned off?... headaches.
3. In general, I would recommend using `POST` as a form's method instead of `GET`; when you use `GET`, you expose the params etc. right in the URL when you hit the submit button... and
4. Do not use `POST` or `GET` values directly within your SQL statement. Use prepared statements and always sanitize user inputs... As a golden rule of thumb: **NEVER trust the user** :)

Comment: @JoshuaJohn amended my answer

Answer (score 1):

Dates, assuming they are in the right format, need to be in quotes like this

```
BETWEEN '".$_GET["ftxtKeyword"]."' AND '".$_GET["btxtKeyword"]."'";
```

The right format would be `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: oh comeon... beat me by like seconds! :p

Comment: I do apologise @Rushikumar

Comment: @Rushikumar And you got my UV also